# Manifolds with corners and Black holes

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

So I've heard that the definition of a singularity is a place where a geodesic cannot be extended smoothly. Which brings up the questions, have there been attempts to do this non-smoothly? Is the result trivial? If you give up smoothness but replace it by some weaker notion of differentiabilty can you do it?

Comment: Your question is badly lacking details. At the very least, you should provide a reference to the claim.  In Riemannian Geometry there are some situations when you can embed a manifold isometrically as an open subset of a larger metric space. Maybe this is what you are asking about...